# Does Material Design Library work with eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, material-design

I googled for this purpose but I couldn't find any answer for my question but I found Android Material Design with android studio , my question here is there any way to add Material Design Library to my android project in Eclipse.

thanks for any comment.

Comment: **Obviously** it does. It doesn't depend on the **IDE**, Check out [this](http://blog.axxg.de/android-entwicklung-eclipse-material-design-android-4/). It's in German, but it's **all pictures**, so, it's very easy to follow even if you don't know German.

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks for your comment but first of all I have to add android  L to my eclipse right ?

Comment: Of course, you must have the SDK installed (21+). Simply do all the upgrades in the SDK Manager, then (when finished) Help/Check for Updates in Eclipse.

Comment: This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @DerGolem sorry just if I create an app using android L it should be work on other devices right ? especially lower versions.

Comment: It depends. You must set the **minSDKVersion** to the lowest API Level you want to support. And use the **support.library versions** of the objects and the methods. i.e. Use `NotificationCompat` instead of `Notification`, use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`...

Comment: As suggested by @JHH, I collected my comments to an answer. So you can remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously it does.
It doesn't depend on the IDE, Check out [this](http://blog.axxg.de/android-entwicklung-eclipse-material-design-android-4/).
It's in German, but it's all pictures, so, it's very easy to follow even if you don't know German.

Mind that you must have the SDK installed (21+). Simply do all the upgrades in the SDK Manager, then (when finished) Help/Check for Updates in Eclipse.

To make the newer SDK design apps work on lower level devices, you must set the **minSDKVersion** to the lowest API Level you want to support.
And use the **support.library versions** of the objects and the methods.

i.e.:

- Use `NotificationCompat` instead of `Notification`
- Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`, ...

Comment: Thanks for your kind support @DerGolem